# How to cast void* to long long in C?

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I am using a 32-bit system. I wanted to cast void* to long long(64-bit). I have tried as below and I am not getting expected values.

```
printf("size of long long is %d and unsigned int is %d\n", sizeof(long long), sizeof(unsigned int));

void* ptr = 12340000;
long long test = (long long)ptr;

printf("the value of the ptr is %d\n", ptr);
printf("the value of the test is %d\n", test);
```

The output for the above code is:

```
size of long long is 8 and unsigned int is 4
the value of the ptr is 12340000
the value of the test is 1610658408
```

Comment: What are your expected values??

Comment: `%d` is neither the correct `printf` format for `void*` (should be `%p`) nor `long long` (should be `%lld`).

Comment: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t` - the correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: `uptr_t` is not standard -- `uintptr_t` is the standard unsigned integer type that's large enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you at least three warnings for the posted code fragment, you need to either increase its warning level, or get a better compiler.

Comment: You might also think about *why* you're trying to store a `void *` in a `long long`.  Usually the right thing to store a `void *` in is a `void *`.  Although there are a few specialized situations where it's necessary, usually it's a mistake to try to store pointers into integer variables.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with getting the format strings match the types you pass.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("size of long long is %zu and unsigned int is %zu\n", sizeof(long long), sizeof(unsigned int));

    void* ptr = (void *) 12340000;
    long long test = (long long) ptr;

    printf("the value of the ptr is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("the value of the test is %lld\n", test);
}
```

If you want to check `text` in hexadecimal (hint: use `%llx`) you will see it is probably the same as `ptr` in a slightly different representation. You shouldn't cast a `void *` to `long long` without testing if that actually provides the correct results on your platform.

But be very careful with format strings. For `sizeof` you should use `%zu`, for `void *` it is `%p` and for `long long` it is `%lld`.

The cast to `long long` is just: `(long long)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main question is, I wanted to cast the void* to long long. Here, my input is void * and I need to load into long long variable.

Comment: And I literally answered that.